# Avoid null columns on export to csv

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this;

```
 col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5
 A1   |B1   |C1   |D1   |E1
 A2   |B2   |NULL |NULL |NULL
```

Using COPY TO CSV I get this result;

```
 A1|B1|C1|D1|
 A2|B2|||
```

But what I need is this;

```
 A1|B1|C1|D1|
 A2|B2|
```

Is there a way to achieve this result using COPY in postgresql?

Comment: Why would you want a CSV file with different numbers of columns per row?

Comment: I need a Master-Detail csv. So I'm using a temp table to union Master and Detail table and later I would export to a csv file.

Comment: Your example data supports your idea, but what happens when `B1` in your example is instead `NULL`? Upon reading, `C1` becomes the value for the `col_2` column?

Comment: Yes, but in this particular case it won't happen. Master row will never receive a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to do the string manipulation *before* the copy:

```
select col_1,
       concat_ws('|', col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5)
from t;
```

`concat_ws()` ignores `NULL` values, which seems to be your intention.